# Missing file libarclite_iphoneos.a (Xcode 14.3)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode14

After installing Xcode 14.3 in order to run my app on my iOS 16.3 [iPhone XS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_XS). I get the following error:

> File not found: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 412):

Add the below code to the Podfile. It works for me. Version 14.3 beta 2 (14E5207e)

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
        project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: This worked for me with my flutter app! I changed the target to 11. Xcode 14.3, Flutter 3.7.7, testing out on iPhone 14 Pro Max simulator. This error came out of the blue today it seems like.

Comment: This solution works for me. Instead of 13.0, I set the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 11.0 only. I'm using Xcode v14.3 on macOS Ventura 13.3. Make sure you run pod install again after enter the given code on your podfile. ^_^

Comment: What if I am not using Pods? How to resolve this?

Comment: @Developer Try this way, in Xcode Build Settings, search IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET, set at least iOS 11.0. if it doesn't help, try next  anwser.

Comment: The [latest Flutter version (3.3.10)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123890#issuecomment-1498164468) includes a fix! No need to mess with the `Info.plist` anymore.

Comment: Doesn't work .  Use @JustAimz's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75867043/9185411. 

IMPORTANT!replace the existing post_install with the given one

Comment: I set it to  `config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '16.4'`, not realizing that this caused my app to crash on older device (because I was only looking at the general App Deployment Target)  ...

Comment: The solution does work for my issue. My xcode detail: Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)
Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the code in? [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29)? [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29)?

Answer (score 261):

**Open [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)#Terminal) and go to the following folder:**

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/
```

**Create the folder** ***"arc":***

Go to *System Preferences* → *Security & Privacy* → *Full Disk Access* → *Terminal*, and do:

```
sudo mkdir arc
cd  arc
sudo git clone https://github.com/kamyarelyasi/Libarclite-Files.git .
```

**Give the necessary permissions:**

```
sudo chmod +x *
```

***Now you will be able to build and run, but not Archive.***

To fix this, follow the steps:

In Xcode, navigate to:

- *Pods* → *Target Support Files* → *Pods-Runner or Pods-App*
- Open file *Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh* or *Pods-App-frameworks.sh*
- Find the line: `source="$(readlink "${source}")"`
- Replace it by: `source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`

**Then...Archive**

[image]

Comment: Big thanks. This works for me:
1 - Download files from Libarclite-Files
2- Add them to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/

Comment: thanks, just move cloned files from the Libarclite folder ( /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/ ) to the parent folder (in the lib folder ), then give permission to it.

Comment: Before changing Symlinked in Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh run:
`pod install`

Comment: I wanna point out that it's not a good idea to give random files from GitHub *root* and executable permissions

Comment: I did it same think it's not work but I copy "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib" folder data to parent folder "usr" . It's will fine

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad i read it somewhere that statement was pods path getting updated so pods are not readable on old path that's why it's happened.

Comment: I don't have pod files can any suggest what to do in that case

Comment: For me I just create arc directory and download the Libarclite-Files folder manually and put all files into the arc directory.

Comment: It worked ! It the terminal not working (permission deny) , create folder and copy manually.

Comment: Sometimes the system does not allow creating and copying files using commands. In that case, create a folder on the desktop and clone files into the desktop folder. Once it is completed, copy and paste the path from above. This method worked for me. Also, there is no need to use [sudo chmod +x *].

Answer (score 174):

You can manually modify the minimum deployment version of the third-party framework.

e.g.: iOS 8.0 --> iOS 11.0

[image: An image showing a settings menu within xcode. On the left side, 'Pods' is selected. Then, 'General' is selected. In the center of the screen, a dropdown menu with the title "Minimum Deployments" is higlighted, and is currently set to iOS 8.0.]

Comment: For me, it was my FMDB dependency that needed to be updated to 11.0. Then everything worked.

Comment: This works for me after I set ALL pods to the same iOS version.

Comment: This happened to me for a completely diff pod file (not flutter). And also this solution worked for me. And I'll tell you why this is the best answer... 
1. There is NO reason for anyone to install libarclite_iphoneos.a
2. This mod is clean and you dont have to write yet another script file to fix this error..

Comment: @MatthewTrent Updated FMDB deployment target from 8 to 11 did it, thanks.

Comment: I also had to manually update some related pods (Firebase+Core+Analytics+etc.), and I repeated this step for other pods until I stopped getting the error.

Answer (score 78):

Actually, the other answers are correct, but to an amateur, it's still quite difficult to figure it out.

It seems like iOS stopped supporting iOS 8, so the minimum should be 11.0.

There are two ways to upgrade your iOS:

1. Manually update *all* targets with a minimum deployment at 11.0.

   [image]

   It will work perfectly but tiring, so...
2. Adjust the pod code to force all targets with a minimum deployment at 11.0.

   [image]

   ```
    post_install do |installer|
        installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
              project.targets.each do |target|
                  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
                   end
              end
       end
    end
   ```

   Remember to clean and de-integrate pod and re-install it.

   ```
    cd [project directory]
    pod deintegrate
    pod clean
    pod install
   ```

Comment: My attached pictures are minimum deployment 12.0 cuz, some of my dependencies require higher than 11.0

Comment: 'pod clean' no longer exists

Comment: Thanks, 1st solution is enough to work, no need to go for second one. Set minimum deployment at 11.0.

Comment: @KasunUdaraJayasekara first solution you have to update manually everytime whenever pod install/re-install. Second solution is one time change.

Comment: `pod clean` doesn't exist. Use `pod cache clean --all` instead

Comment: 1st solution also worked for me (I only had one target). God bless @Nguyen Tan Dat! The Lord Always Delivers!

Answer (score 71):

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
        project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
            end
        end
    end
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    end
end
```

This is the right code for podfile.

Comment: Being a complete novice here, how and where do I implement this script?

Comment: I want my app to support down to iOS 11, will this affect it?

Comment: @Andy You need to add this to the end of your Podfile file, found in the ios directory of your application. There will be another structure that looks like 

```post_install do |installer| 
    {logic}
end```

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day! Also updated minimum deployment version of Pods.xcodeproj to same as main project. After that exec `pod install`, clean build folder and build project.

Comment: It works. Xcode 14.3. Don't forget to pod install, then clean.

Comment: Still work with 14.6, "pod install" after edit and then it works perfectly.

Comment: Works perfect with modified  ['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0' as well.

Answer (score 36):

I updated the `post_install` in my Podfile to:

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
      end
    end
  end

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Additionally, I set the *Minimum Deployments* to 13 as well (*Runner* → *Targets* → *Runner*):

[image: Xcode target minimum deployment target]

After this, I updated the project's pods by running this in the terminal:

```bash
cd ios;

# Remove the pods
pod deintegrate;

# Remove the Podfile.lock
rm -f Podfile.lock;

# Installs the pods
pod install --repo-update;
```

Try running the app from your IDE; it should work now.

If you continue to have issues, try cleaning the build folder within Xcode and running the app, also within Xcode.

[image: Xcode clean build folder]

Once you have successfully run the app from Xcode, go back to your IDE and you'll be able to run the app.

Comment: This works but now I can't build xcarchive or ipa. Do you have any fixes for this? Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: tonly this answer works for me

Answer (score 28):

## Update

[This answer could be valid for the question in this topic as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75909590/4546246)

## The old answer

It's worked for me.

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/

sudo mkdir arc

# While executing the above command, the OS will block it
# and give an error. Allow permission from the settings
# and run the command again.

cd arc
sudo git clone https://github.com/kamyarelyasi/Libarclite-Files.git .
```

You may also need to run this command: sudo `chmod +x *`

Comment: it work for me when I put 

`sudo git clone https://github.com/kamyarelyasi/Libarclite-Files.git .`

Comment: I edited the post to include `sudo` before the `git clone`

Comment: It had worked for me without `sudo` before. Still, there's no harm, it can be added.

Comment: Good and Quick Solution. It works

Comment: Please change your answer to [not use "edit"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles/131011#131011) (near *"Changelogs"*). The answer should be as if it was written right now.

Comment: I needed to do `sudo chmod +x *` after these steps. My Nativescript can now see  it fine.

Answer (score 25):

Since Xcode 14.3 you have to set all your Pods to a minimum deployment target of iOS 11. Then it will work.

1. Navigate to the [Pods] project in the Project Navigator.
2. Select "each" target under it and perform step 3 below.
3. Change the *Minimum Deployment Target* to *iOS 11* version in the drop-down list therein.

Answer (score 17):

After updating to XCode 14.3 I got the same error message as described in the question. In my case it was an error in a pod that was shown. My project is a native iOS app and no flutter like answers from others seem to be dealing with.

The following worked for me:

1. Comment out all pods in Podfile by adding `# in front of each pod`.
2. Close XCode.
3. Run `pod install` (will remove all pods).
4. Open `xcworkspace` project in XCode again and do a clean (`command-shift-k`).
5. `Uncomment pods` in Podfile and add this before the last end in the Podfile (`change 11.0 to the minimum version you want to support`):

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
        project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

6. Close XCode.
7. Run pod install.
8. Open xcworkspace project in XCode and error should be gone.

Comment: Worked for me as well after upgrading to Xcode 14.3

Comment: Thank God for Stack Overflow. Updating Xcode is always a terrifying experience. For native iOS apps, this is my favorite answer.

Answer (score 16):

From the Flutter team.

No need for workarounds, just update Flutter to latest version `3.7.11` and run `flutter upgrade` in your project, and you should be good.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/124433.

Just tested in my Flutter project, and I can confirm I can build and archive the xcode project

Answer (score 16):

If you are working in Swift/Objective-C, **No** further action is needed except:

1. Navigate to **[Pods]** project in the Project Navigator.
2. Select **"each" target** under it and perform the step 3 below.
3. Change the **Minimum Deployments** value to the **lowest available version** in the drop-down list therein. (***Avoid typing in the version, manually***)

[image]

Thereafter, **clean build folder** from **Product** Menu, and hopefully you'll be able to build the project successfully.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.

Comment: @HangarRash Please take another look at my answer. It is well-written, straightforward and advises the readers against any unnecessary hassle such as adding extra code to the pod file, restarting Xcode etc. mentioned in other answers. More importantly, the step 2 is a must because the issue will not be resolved until it is ensured that each and every target is set to the lowest available version shown in the Minimum Deployments dropdown.

Answer (score 14):

Here are the step-by-step instructions, including the image links:

1. Open a web browser and go to the following URL: https://github.com/kamyarelyasi/Libarclite-Files
2. On the GitHub page, you will see a list of files. Locate the file named `libarclite_iphonesimulator.a`.

   [image: GitHub Files]
3. Click on the file name (`libarclite_iphonesimulator.a`) to open it.
4. On the file page, click the "Download" button to download the file to your computer. Choose a suitable location to save the file.
5. After the download is complete, locate the downloaded file (`libarclite_iphonesimulator.a`) on your computer.
6. Open the Finder application on your Mac.
7. In the menu bar, click on "Go" and select "Go to Folder" from the dropdown menu.
8. In the "Go to the folder" dialog box, enter the following path and click the "Go" button:
   `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/`

   [image: Go to Folder]
9. If the `arc` directory does not exist in the specified path, right-click on the "arc" folder in the Finder and select "New Folder" from the context menu. Rename the newly created folder as "arc".
10. Now, locate the downloaded file (`libarclite_iphonesimulator.a`) and copy it.
11. Go back to the Finder window containing the `arc` directory.
12. Right-click on an empty space within the `arc` directory and select "Paste Item" from the context menu. This will paste the copied file (`libarclite_iphonesimulator.a`) into the `arc` directory.
13. Once the file is successfully copied, you have completed the process of downloading the files and copying the `libarclite_iphonesimulator.a` file to the specified location.

Comment: I succeed by this way, thanks

Answer (score 13):

Just create a folder called 'arc' in the following path:

> /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/

Download and paste the contents of this repository into the folder you just created and then build again.

> https://github.com/kamyarelyasi/Libarclite-Files

Comment: This did not work for as i keep getting "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" and I did flutter clean and even run pod install but still.

Comment: @yendis, did you try an earlier solution suggested here itself -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/75924853/1349159 It worked for me

Comment: It solves the issue partially. After doing this, you can build and run the app but Archiving for uploading AppStore still fails.

Answer (score 12):

I spent hours and I've found out the problem. It was Xcode version 14.3.

I tried the above suggestions (update your podfile) and it worked, but the problem is you can't build [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa) files or XCArchives.

Here's what I did in my case:

1. I downloaded Xcode version 14.2 here https://xcodereleases.com/
2. Just set the Command Line Tools to Xcode 14.2

P.S.: Just to make sure, run the usual first:

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get
```

With this, I was able to build and create XCArchives. I hope this helps other Flutter developers!

[image: Xcode Settings]

Answer (score 10):

I figured out the problem. I had to increase the deployment target for the Pod module that was causing the error to iOS 15.0. At least, that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

**tl;dr: Change deployment target without downgrading pods**

Many answers here are about updating `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` in the `post_install` hook of Cocoapods. I had to tweak this solution a little bit, since my project uses pods which already have a higher deployment target, and the provided solutions would downgrade them, causing their build to break (e.g. when the pods are using newer APIs).

So here's my patched approach, to only change the deployment target if it's too low:

```rb
post_install do | installer |
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'].split('.').first.to_i < 11
          config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep this seem the best answer for multiple pod versions. I use it like this: post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   if config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] == '8.0'
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
      end
    end
  end
end

Answer (score 9):

My system: [MacBook Pro M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Sixth_generation_(M1))

Xcode: 14.3

---

To fix this issue, you must ensure that the iOS Deployment Target of your pods is **11.0**; pods with an iOS Deployment Target of 8.0 were **causing the issue** for me.

Example: pods that were set to iOS Deployment Target 8.0: leveldb-library, nanopb.

You will receive this error for any pods that are set to 8.0 when building, so change them to 11.0 either manually or with a post install script in your Podfile.

Comment: prefect work for me.

Comment: Actually From Xcode 14.3, it supports 11.0 min Deployment Target.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing worked for me. I just downgraded Xcode to 14.2 and it worked!

Comment: This worked. The issue is related to new Xcode. I downgraded and it worked like charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding this code to the Pod file

```
    post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Don't use this code

```
    post_install do |installer|
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
          project.targets.each do |target|
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
               end
          end
   end
end
```

Comment: is it flutter environment?  flutter_additional_ios_build_settings

Answer (score 3):

It seems like some files are missing from Xcode 14.3 above (including Xcode 15). You can add them back by this command:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/MojtabaHs/xcode-arc `xcode-select -p`/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc
```

<sub>This will add them to the currently selected Xcode.
You can select another Xcode using `xcode-select` command and run the above command again to make it work too.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. First update `PodFile`.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
        end
    end
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Update target as per your need. For me `11.0` was minimum requirement. This basically updates `minimum deployments` from anything you have to `11.0` so you don’t need to update manually.

Now `Missing file libarclite_iphoneos.a` must be fixed. However, you might get another issue while generating build. If so, please go through following steps.

#### 2. Can't generate build?

**.sh Path:** `flutter-project-folder/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh`

**Steps**

1. Open `Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh` file from sublime (or any other)
2. Search for `source="$(readlink "${source}")"` and replace it with `source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`
3. Run `flutter build ipa --release`
4. `[important]` Now open sublime again. You will see it will remove `-f`. At this time immediately add `-f` again and save the file. Now the build should be successful.

This worked for me. Hope this helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For me, macOS project, increase the minimum deployments version for that target.

Answer (score 2):

**Fixed in Flutter 3.7.11**

```
flutter upgrade
```

---

*[Upgrading to Xcode 14.3 will not build when plugin transitive dependencies have a low deployment target: File not found: XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a #124340](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/124340)*

*[Hotfixes to the Stable Channel](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel)*

Answer (score 2):

In one line:

Just search for "iphoneos_deployment_target" in your Xcode and change any target lower than 11.0 to 11.0.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to improve [moveFastLink's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574268/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-xcode-14-3/75729977#75729977).

There are two things that I think could be improved:

- In moveFastLink's solution, when one of the pods already has a higher deployment target, it will be "downgraded" to `13.0`.
- OP asks for a solution that solves his problem. For the problem to be solved, it's not necessary so set the target version of every pod to `13.0`. Instead, `11.0` very much suffices.

For these reasons I propose to add this to the `Podfile` of your project:

```rb
wanted_project_target = 11.0

post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        current_project_target = config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'].to_f

        if current_project_target < wanted_project_target
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = wanted_project_target.to_s
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This piece of code checks if the current `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` is lower than the `wanted_project_target` and only re-assigns it to `wanted_project_target` if this is the case.

Comment: What is the code in? Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Update the Flutter SDK to 3.7.12 to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**100% Working and Tested**

For my case, I was getting an error like below:

[image]

When I have updated my Xcode with the latest version, my running project was getting an error.

**Executable path is a directory**

Later I saw the below error in Xcode:

[image]

This is how I resolved this:

By using a terminal, I have added the *src* directory and changed its permissions

1. Open the [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)#Terminal) application in your Mac.
2. Enter the command:

   ```
   sudo mkdir arc
   ```
3. It will ask for permission if you haven't set permissions previously for access in *App Management*.

   [image]
4. Enter this command in the terminal:

   ```
   cd  arc
   ```
5. Enter this command in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo git clone https://github.com/kamyarelyasi/Libarclite-Files.git .
   ```

Once this command fired, now it is time to change permissions:

```
sudo chmod +x *
```

Almost done.

Simply search in Xcode for the following:

```
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
```

and just replace it by the following:

```
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```

It looks like:

[image]

*Done*. You are able to generate a build and are also able to run in the simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into this issue with the [LevelDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB) [CocoaPod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CocoaPods) (a dependency of FirebaseFirestore and FirebaseDatabase), we've published a version of *[leveldb-library](https://cocoapods.org/pods/leveldb-library)* (1.22.2), with updated minimum Apple platform versions to be compatible with Xcode 14. Run `pod update` to get 1.22.2.

Comment: It updated to 1.22.2 (Installing leveldb-library 1.22.2 (was 1.22.1) but didn't worked.

Comment: Your app may be using other pods besides Firebase which have the issue. If it's only leveldb and Firebase, please provide the detail at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues and we'll investigate.

Answer (score 0):

```
Inside script "Pods-${TARGET}-frameworks.sh"
Inside function install_framework()
...
# Use filter instead of exclude so missing patterns don't throw errors.
# 
# 1. fix framework path at $source variable
#    framework not found at script location
source="${1}"

echo "rsync --delete -av "${RSYNC_PROTECT_TMP_FILES[@]}" --links --filter \"- CVS/\" --filter \"- .svn/\" --filter \"- .git/\" --filter \"- .hg/\" --filter \"- Headers\" --filter \"- PrivateHeaders\" --filter \"- Modules\" \"${source}\" \"${destination}\""

# 2. replace rsync --links flag with --copy-links 
#    rsync will copy files and directories instead do symlinkink
#    if don't do this, later code sign failed, when try to codesign symbolic link
rsync --delete -av "${RSYNC_PROTECT_TMP_FILES[@]}" --copy-links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "${source}" "${destination}"
...
That's all ctrl+s and archive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the offending pod in the errors (yellow). I just changed that to my target (14)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using Pods to add Firebase to my app. What fixed it for me was: Select the ‘Pods’ project in the the file navigation on the left, then select the ‘General’ tab, select the ‘leveldb-library’ target and set the minimum deployment to iOS 11.0.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this issue by upgrading the [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) iOS minimum deployment (8 for me) to 11 inside Pods general.

Comment: Re *"FMBD"*: Presumably you meant *[FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)* (?)

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the iOS version 11.0 or higher solved my problem!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can copy ‘libarclite_iphoneos.a’ from Xcode 14.2 to Xcode 14.3. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Select Pods Project --> select all the pods target --> Goto Build Settings
Then make sure iOS Deployment Target like the below

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You just need to update your pods to the newest version.

I reinstalled [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) with [rvm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_Version_Manager) and updated [CocoaPods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CocoaPods).
After that I updated my pods to the newest version and everything worked fine (for me).

Answer (score -2):

I have fixed this issue by manually going to the libraries and changing version 8.0 to 13.0 for each library. See in screenshot:

[image]

Comment: And the next time you do "pod install" you will have to do this all over again.

Comment: Yes, and all of that is covered in several other answers. You should delete your answer.