# Xcode 14.3 "no such module '__ObjC'"

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

Xcode Screenshot:

[image]

Project Details:

- The project is an Objective-C project originally created in 2012.
- Roughly 33% of the code base is now in Swift.
- Project has Cocoapod dependencies.
- Project compiles with no issues on Xcode 14.2

Xcode 14.3 Issue:

- On Xcode 14.3 project does not build and the errors thrown are in Xcode generated files ProjectName.private.swiftinterface and ProjectName.swiftinterface
- Xcode says 'no such module __ObjC'

  - failed to verify module interface 'ProjectName' due to errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
- See attached screenshot for full a visual.

What we've tried:

- pod install --repo-update
- full project clean, delete Derived Data folder, clean again, try to build again.

Question:

- Does the community think this is an Xcode issue? Or is there something wrong in our Build Settings/Info.plist file? Has anyone encountered this before?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Posting as answer per a commenter suggestion:

In the case of this project what solved the issue was setting the "Build Libraries for Distribution" flag to "No". The errors went away, and the project now compiles in Xcode 14.3.

Comment: under what heading in xcode? Where do i find this?

Comment: Click on your project file in Xcode, then in the Targets select the Project, then Build Settings tab, and search Build Libraries for Distribution. That sets it globally. You can also do it individually for a Pod in the Pods, Build Settings.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be universal. I need to be able to Archive my project which I can't seem to do with this setting unchecked. I can build it though...

Comment: Thanks man!, its been a week, i have been checking the issue. finally it got resolved. but i wonder why the Build Libraries for Distribution effect __objC module?

Comment: Have you found any solution for Archiving with this error and XC 14.3 ? The solution works for development, this is not a normal behaviour for production build :/

Comment: I don't know if this might help, but if you're using cocoapods an archiving issue we encountered was solved by changing source="$(readlink "${source}")" in the Pods-[ProjectName]-frameworks file to source="$(readlink -f "$source")". Article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574268/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-xcode-14-3

Comment: It worked but what about when this app goes to distribution? :) will it matter?

Answer (score 1):

Linking as static frameworks by adding **use_frameworks! :linkage => :static** to your Podfile. Flipper does not work when use_frameworks is enabled, and you should remove it from Podfile.

Adding the **-no-verify-emitted-module-interface** flag to failing targets to avoid verification failure.
You can add the following post install hook to your Podfile to automatically add this flag. In my case my Pods were AEP so I used "AEP".

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
    if t.name.start_with?("AEP")
      t.build_configurations.each do |bc|
          bc.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] = '$(inherited) -no-verify-emitted-module-interface'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

https://github.com/adobe/aepsdk-rulesengine-ios/issues/68#issuecomment-1548199715

Answer (score -1):

I experience the same. I guess it's an Xcode issue, since it works with the prior version. In the meantime I use `@_implementationOnly import` to get rid of it.

Comment: Can you clarify where you added this? Thx