# Unable to run build in Xcode 14.3. Due to missing arc file

Tags: flutter, xcode, xcode14

I just installed Xcode 14.3 and it is showing me and error during running app:

```
Error (Xcode): File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

Answer (score 5):

add this **config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.4'** in podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.4'
             if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
              end
            end
          end
```

Comment: For me answer from the following link Edimar Martins works correctly:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574268/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-xcode-14-3