# Xcode Error after update to 16.4. This error happened when I updated Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

> ld: file not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I need to know how to resolve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing file libarclite\_iphoneos.a (Xcode 14.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574268/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-xcode-14-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using pods, try to set the iOS Deployment Target of every libraries to 11.0.

You can add the code `config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'` to your podfile like below:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
      end
    end
  end
end
```