# File not found: ibarclite_iphonesimulator.a

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I get the following error when trying to build my IOS project and view it in the iPhone simulator. Can someone please help?

```
File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing file libarclite\_iphoneos.a (Xcode 14.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574268/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-xcode-14-3)

Comment: Please check below comment hopefully it'll help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75924853/3185290)