# How I can resolve "Framework not found Pods_Next_Tremity_Push_Notification_Live" error?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

[image]

I am creating my own Push Notification-only app called "Next_Tremity Push Notification Live". It's designed for people can receive Notifications about my previously App Store-approved gift stickers apps, my referral links, my new devices, and my own other things.

Help me by giving me solution(s) to resolve "Framework not found Pods_Next_Tremity_Push_Notification_Live" error?

I had to use pods and Google Firebase for my own Push Notification-only app. I decided to develop my own Push Notification-only app and fixed some errors by found solutions on Google Search.

I used Xcode 14.3 to develop my own Push Notification-only app on my M1 Max MacBook Pro 16". It's running macOS Ventura 13.3.1 at this time.

Comment: I have seen this error when My Mac is selected under run device. Also when project is open instead of workspace. But may also be because of XCode 14.3 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75980471/5881884