# Why I don't have Pods-Runner or Pods-App in my xcode project?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to follow Edimar Martins's answer to solve the issue that was asked in this link: [Missing file libarclite_iphoneos.a (Xcode 14.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574268/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-xcode-14-3)

By following the first step,  I am able to run and build now but still not able to archive.  The reason is I could not find the Pods\Target Support Files\Pods-Runner or Pods-App in my project.
Could anyone give me some help, please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8DAb.png)

I have cleaned the build folder and run pod install again.