# Flutter app fails to run on iOS simulator after switching from Xcode 14.2 to 14.3

Tags: flutter, xcode, firebase

I recently switched from Xcode 14.2 to 14.3 and now my Flutter app fails to run on the iOS simulator. Here's the error output from Xcode:

Launching lib/main.dart on iPad mini (6th generation) in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            3.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
2023-04-29 00:21:38.923 xcodebuild[12573:160868] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
{ id:17D8789D-DC56-43C1-B1EE-964E5EE01320 }

```
    Available destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
        { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
```

Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/23/7lnnj_09535f5kpq9g_twph40000gn/T/flutter_tools.iHnNsp/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirz0h6e4/temporary_xcresult_bundle

I've tried deleting the Xcode derived data, but the problem persists. I can successfully run the app on a new project, but the issue only occurs with my old project.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and found a solution? I'd appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have encountered same problem when i updated my mac to latest update, as i updated my mac, xcode also upgraded then my flutter app were not run, so i down grade xcode to my last version,     in short - downgrade your xcode

Comment: i did that and it works but is there a solution for that because i am not able to test the app in newer version of ios

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this error too, so I found a workaround for this here: [Missing file libarclite_iphoneos.a (Xcode 14.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574268/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-xcode-14-3)

Basically, you need to add this code in your Podfile, in my case, I've got this code:

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end

  # workaround code
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
         end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

go to Runner.xcodeproj --> xcshareddata/xc schemes --> Runner.schemes change in this file : buildConfiguration = "Release" to buildConfiguration = "Debug"