# 'benchmark/benchmark.h' file not found Xcode 14.3

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, xcode14

I had a problem with pod, I found my solution with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75729977/20693520

After I do that and fixed my "Missing file libarclite_iphoneos.a" error, I get a new error:

> 'benchmark/benchmark.h' file not found" in "variant_benchmark.cc"

Screenshot of error:

[image: screen_shot_of_'benchmark/benchmark.h' file not found in xcode 14]

I didn't find any solution