# File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Develop.er/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a

Tags: flutter, xcode

I am getting this error in flutter ios xcode .
File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a

I did try
Flutter clean and pub get even clean build but I didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it was something related to the Pods file...

[image]

Check for all your third party libraries (such as FMDB, which is known to cause these issues) and try updating the minimum deployment version. Hope this work for you as there is no official solution for this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574268/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-xcode-14-3?rq=2)